# Add two custom fields as a default to the "new post" page.

Tags: posts, custom-field

I'm using WordPress Version 4.7.2

I'm trying to set up the new post page (wp-admin/post-new.php) so it automatically displays two custom fields. I'd like the custom field "name" pre-populated and the custom field "value" left blank.

**Current New Post Page**

[image]

**Desired New Post Page**

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The below code will add default custom fields to your post ( Insert the code in your themes function.php ) .

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'set_default_custom_fields');
function set_default_custom_fields($post_id){
if ( $_GET['post_type'] == 'post' ) {

add_post_meta($post_id, 'Field Name', '', true);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Another Field Name', '', true);
}
return true;
}
```

By default this will add an empty custom field to your post. If you want to enter a value by default too, use the code below.

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'set_default_custom_fields');
function set_default_custom_fields($post_id){
if ( $_GET['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Field Name', 'Field Value', true);
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I did update my function.php file with the "2nd option" from your answer, but it did not work. I tried the 1st option also, and it didn't work either. I'm attempting to get the custom fields immediately when I click "new post". I don't what to have to select them from the "dropdown" list. I'm using the 'standard' template in a "new post". Ideas? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the best way to add custom-field is to use `add_meta_boxes` action  and [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) function.

When you use this action, custom-field can be place where ever you want.
If you want to pre-populate input value, it will easier, as you dedicated function will be thrown exactly like you want (values could be set).

You will find some more details [add_meta_boxes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes)

Hope it helps